# Use strptime to convert time zone in R

Tags: r, timezone, strptime

An example of my 'date/time' field is:

> 2020-12-30T03:32:30.000Z

I wish to convert this timezone to "tz = Singapore".
When I executed this code,

`geodf$time <- strptime(geodf$time, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS", tz="Singapore")`

the resulting output is:

> "2020-12-30 03:32:30 +08"

The only change it made is the additional label at the back (+08). The timing didn't change at all - I need to change the timing to Singapore's, not just add the +08.

What went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Z` in your time indicates the timezone is UTC. One approach is to use an object of class `POSIXct` and change the timezone:

```
geodf$time <- as.POSIXct(geodf$time,
                         format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS", tz="UTC")
geodf
#                 time
#1 2020-12-30 03:32:30

attributes(geodf$time)$tzone <- "Singapore"
geodf
#                 time
#1 2020-12-30 11:32:30
```

Sample Data:

```
geodf <- structure(list(time = "2020-12-30T03:32:30.000Z"),
                   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This solves my problem perfectly.